# Role ' ' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am add new roles in mvc 4 app ... but every time it gives this Error

here is my Register Method

```
 //
        // POST: /Account/Register
         [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                object x = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

                if (Membership.GetUser(model.UserName) == null)
                {
                    // Attempt to register the user
                    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                    Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null,
                        out createStatus);

                    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                    {


                        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);

 //model.Role is the DropDown Selected Text.. its value is 'Admin'

                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,   
   false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "EUT");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("",  
     ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Already exists");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

In My Web Config

```
 <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true"  defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
                                    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
                                    cookieName=".myroles"
                                    cookieTimeout="30"
                                    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
                                    cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

I have seen similar posts :

[Add User Roles on Registration (Forms Authentication) MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282938/add-user-roles-on-registration-forms-authentication-mvc3?rq=1)

[Adding users to roles on registring failed ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116969/adding-users-to-roles-on-registring-failed-asp-net-mvc3)

[Adding roles only adding one to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158936/adding-roles-only-adding-one-to-user)

In tried to bind selected value with model property ...still it is not working ...

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: `Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role)` What's `model.Role` at this point?

Comment: model.Role is the DropDown Selected Text

Comment: What's its value, not what is it.

Comment: Are you double sure that the value is being set in `model.Role`?

Comment: On the debugger ...model.UserName=="MyName" and model.Role = "admin" (DDL selected Text)shows

Comment: Is this Role set up in the database?

Comment: my aspnet_Roles is null by Default ...should i Manually Add Roles there ?

Comment: Ok ..add this code solved my Problem 

     if (!Roles.RoleExists(model.Role))
     {
      Roles.CreateRole(model.Role);
     }
    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);

Comment: Cant add answer as I dont have reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the role exists and add it if it doesn't like this:

```
var adminRoleExists = Roles.RoleExists(AppRoles.Admin.ToString());
if (!adminRoleExists)
{
    Roles.CreateRole(AppRoles.Admin.ToString());
}
```